How do operations on permutation matrices work?
Recently, while studying the Leibniz determinant, I learned that a permutation that swaps rows or columns can act as a matrix. I found a related Wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) and read the following:

Given two permutations of n elements σ and τ, the product of the corresponding column-based permutation matrices Cσ and Cτ is given, as you might expect, by
Cσ Cτ = Cσ∘τ,
where the composed permutation σ∘τ applies first τ and then σ, working from right to left:
(σ∘τ)(k) = σ(τ(k)).
This follows because pre-multiplying some matrix by Cτ and then pre-multiplying the resulting product by Cσ gives the same result as pre-multiplying just once by the combined Cσ∘τ 

For the row-based matrices, there is a twist: The product of Rσ and Rτ is given by
Rσ Rτ = Rτ∘σ,
with σ applied before τ in the composed permutation. This happens because we must post-multiply to avoid inversions under the row-based option, so we would post-multiply first by Rσ and then by Rτ.

After looking at the matrix group section at the bottom of the Wikipedia, I understood that depending on the order in which the two permutations act, the row or column operation changes (since permutations and permutation matrices are essentially the same). Consequently, it became clear that multiplying Rσ and Cσ for a single permutation σ results in the identity matrix, which naturally follows from these properties.
However, what happens if multiply Rσ and Cτ for two different permutations σ and τ?
In fact, when I actually performed the operation for the two permutations
$\sigma\colon\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\3&2&4&1\end{pmatrix} \quad \quad \quad \tau\colon\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&4&1&3\end{pmatrix}$
the result of $R_\sigma \times C_\tau$ was
$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$
which does not seem to correspond to the multiplication of the permutations $\sigma$ and $\tau$.
(In one-line notation, the product of the two should be either 2134 or 1432 depending on the direction of multiplication.)
At this point, should we understand the multiplication as simply the product of two matrices rather than the multiplication of permutations, as in the case of multiplying row or column permutations? Why is that?

Sorry, the wording might be a bit awkward because I'm using a translation tool.

$R_\sigma = C_{\sigma^{-1}}$, so $R_\sigma C_\tau = C_{\sigma^{-1}} C_\tau = C_{\sigma^{-1}\tau}$.

I missed the fact that the two matrices $R_\sigma$ and $C_\sigma$ are transposes of each other and also inverses of each other. Thank you so much.

Evidently your permutation notation translates into the following matrices for performing permutation $\sigma$ on the rows and permutation $\tau$ on the columns:
$$
R_\sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\quad
C_\tau = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then indeed
$$
R_\sigma C_\tau = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now the question is, do you want to interpret this as a transposition of columns or as a transposition of rows?
If you want it to transpose columns, then you multiply an arbitrary matrix $M$ on the left by $R_\sigma C_\tau$.
Keeping in mind that $R_\sigma = C_\sigma^\top = C_\sigma^{-1} = C_{\sigma^{-1}}$,
you are multiplying on the left by $C_{\sigma^{-1}} C_\tau$,
which transposes the columns by $\tau$ and then by $\sigma^{-1}$.
If you want to transpose rows, then you multiply an arbitrary matrix $M$ on the right by $R_\sigma C_\tau$, and since $C_\tau = R_{\tau^{-1}}$,
this permutes the rows by $\sigma$ and then by $\tau^{-1}$.
In other words, $R_\sigma C_\tau = C_{\sigma^{-1}\tau} = R_{\tau^{-1}\sigma}$.
If you wrote $C_\tau R_\sigma$ instead, there would be another interpretation: $C_\tau R_\sigma = C_\tau I R_\sigma$,
where $I$ is the $4\times4$ identity matrix, so $C_\tau R_\sigma$
is the result when you permute the rows of $I$ by $\sigma$ and the columns by $\tau$. Those two permutations are commutative because they are permuting two different sets of indices.
